# Perform a similar group by/sum SQL statement using Entity Framework and C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a header invoice table (`Header`) and detail table (`Detail`) in SQL Server, really there are a lot of columns in the tables, but the main columns are:

- `Header`: Id, InvoiceNumber
- `Detail`: IdDetail, Cost, Id

Using EF I had mapped the tables to classes automatically by scaffolding method. I want to perform a similar SQL query:

```
select 
    a.id, a.InvoiceNumber, sum(b.cost)
from 
    Header a
inner join 
    Detail b on a.id = b.id
where 
    a.id = 1
group by 
    a.id, a.InvoiceNumber
```

The cost is in the `Detail` table because each product in details has its own cost. I need to sum all products costs.

I have tried to do following:

```
var query = _context.Header
                    .GroupJoin(_context.Details, header => header.Id, det => det.Id,
                        (header, det) => new DocumentDTO
                        {
                            Id = header.Id,
                            InvoiceNumber = header.InvoiceNumber,
                            TotalCost = det.Sum(d => d.Cost)
                        }
                    )
                    .Where(x => x.Id == 1);

var x = query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error:

> The LINQ expression
>
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: header => header.Id,
> innerKeySelector: det => det.IdD,
> resultSelector: (header, det) => new DocumentDTO{
> Id = header.Id,
> InvoiceNumber = header.InvoiceNumber,
> TotalCost = det
> .AsQueryable()
> .Sum(d => d.Cost)
> }
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

I think I can not do that I am trying to do. Please, how to perform the SQL statement using Entity Framework?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show `Header` and `Detail` classes, especially navigation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need any `.GroupBy` or other join if you have the right navigation property;

```cs
_context.Header
    .Where(h => h.Id == 1)
    .Select(
        h => new DocumentDTO { 
            Id = h.Id, 
            InvoiceNumber = h.InvoiceNumber,
            TotalCost = h.Detail.Sum(b => b.cost)
        }
    )
```

Comment: Hello Jeremy.  The issue is the Column Cost belongs to Detail class.  In your code you use only Header class.  Is it possible for you rewrite de code considering it? please

Comment: Have you defined a navigation property to represent the foreign key? I have assumed that `h.Detail` is that navigation property.

Comment: You are right!  Thank you!  I realize you wrote h.Detail.sum

Answer (score 1):

EF Core doesn't translate `GroupJoin` in many cases because relational databases can't represent a collection of client-side objects. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators).